# IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET is set to 8.0 Xcode 12 (Flutter)

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, ios-simulator

I run my Flutter project in Android Studio, pod installation goes well but Xcode build fails at the end every time like 20/30 steps first of complete the whole build.
The weird fact is that Android Studio says :

```
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'GoogleDataTransport' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'path_provider' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'BoringSSL-GRPC' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'AppAuth' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'GoogleUtilities' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'GTMAppAuth' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'google_sign_in' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'FirebaseCoreDiagnostics' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'FirebaseCore' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'FirebaseFirestore' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'FirebaseAuth' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'firebase_core' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'firebase_auth' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'cloud_firestore' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'gRPC-Core' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'Firebase' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++-gRPCCertificates-Cpp' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'GoogleSignIn' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'leveldb-library' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'abseil' from project 'Pods')
```

But when I open the workspace with Xcode I see that my target in Runner has `iOS deployment target 14.0` so I don't understand, it should be set to 14 but actually it's 8.
Flutter generated `Podfile`, `Podfile.lock` and `Pods` through `flutter run` I prefer to let Flutter handle Pod generation and installation without using `pod init`, `pod install` or editing `Podfile`.

Comment: Can you share your ios/Podfile?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In addition to what Akif said, here's a running list of reasons why this error could be showing up for you:

1. Set the `MinimumOSversion` to `9.0` in `ios/Flutter/AppFrameworkInfo.plist`
2. In Xcode, ensure that the iOS deployment target at `Runner -> Project -> Runner` is set to `9.0`
3. In Xcode, ensure that the `Deployment Info` in `Runner -> Targets -> Runner` is set to iOS `9.0`
4. Double check that your `GoogleService-Info.plist` is there and was added via Xcode (not copy/pasted into the directory via Finder for example)
5. Uncomment the `#platform :iOS, '9.0'` line in your `ios/Podfile`

Then, run the following in your terminal to build with a fresh state:

```sh
flutter clean \
        && rm ios/Podfile.lock pubspec.lock \
        && rm -rf ios/Pods ios/Runner.xcworkspace \
        && flutter build ios
```

Comment: There isn't "Deployment info" but "Deployment target" instead, and both are set to 14, is it the same?

Comment: I did all these stuffs but when the run ends I have "MinimumiOSVersion" back to 8.0...And the same error again

Comment: @FinleyAdams Make sure you're setting the right `AppFrameworkInfo.plist` that's in `ios/Flutter`. I know there's another `AppFrameworkInfo` that will override at build time which might be the one you're using.

Comment: "flutter build iOS" should be lowercase "flutter build ios"

Comment: Infortunetly I got this : `The Xcode project defines schemes: dev, prod, staging
You must specify a --flavor option to select one of the available schemes.`. I pass the entire day figuring out how to solve this issue.. migrate from 2.0.3 to 2.0.5

Comment: @FinleyAdams Have you got the solution??

Comment: This is non quality to have to specify ios platform in various location...there should be a single entry point...I feel ios coding environment is quite a bugging mess with a lovely interface

Answer (score 14):

replace this code of pod file:

```
post_install do |installer|
 installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
  target.build_configurations.each do |config|
   config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: for flutter apps, `flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)` should be added after line `installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|`.

Answer (score 9):

You need to set `MinimumOSVersion` to `9.0` in `ios/Flutter/AppFrameworkInfo.plist`. It will look like this:

```
  <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
  <string>9.0</string>
```

Comment: I don't have this folder. My path is "ios/Flutter/" and inside Flutter I have "App.framework, flutter_export_enviroment.sh, Flutter.framework, Flutter.podspec, Generated.xconfig".But inside Flutter.framework there's a "Info.plist". And here yes there's the voice "MinimumiOSVersion" and I set it to 14, is it correct?

Comment: No, set it to 9.

Comment: Ok I trust you but why? Isn't better to set it for newer versions?

Comment: No. You are defining the minimum OS version. And It should be at least 9.0 for iOS. And the newer versions like 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 can use your app. But if you set it to 14, then only iOS14 iPhones will use your app.

Comment: Oh you're right thanks! Ok I did it but when the run ends that line has been changed back to 8.0 and I have the same error.

Comment: Follow the steps of @thefoxrocks's answer.

Comment: I did it but I have the same error, maybe Xcode version 12 isn't a good choice?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225151/discussion-between-finley-adams-and-akif).

Comment: I'm in the chat room.

Comment: remove # and uncomment that line in the podfile.
# platform :ios, '9.0'

Comment: Did it but still the same, nothing changed

Comment: I'm in the chat room again.

Comment: you can try to add that line in ios/Runner/info.plist:

<key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
<string>9.0</string>

Comment: @Akif can you help out. having same exact issues.

flutter

Comment: Define the issue in a new question!

Answer (score 3):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zv7dd.jpg)

1. open xcode
2. change Project Document - Project format - Xcode 8.0-Compatible
3. flutter clean, flutter pub get an flutter build ios

Answer (score 3):

Error is self-explanatory that deployment target is missed for application.

This will be added in two places inside Xcode, check the below screenshot where **iOS Deployment Target** is mention.

**1. Runner**

[image]

**2.Pod**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If after trying all the solutions above, your code is still not working, especially after an update/upgrade...

Just check out your dart version and also check out for null safety packages...

I just solved mine after battling with errors for days by properly migrating my codes to null safety.

Comment: what do you mean with check out dart version? and how to solve the issue? could you please elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

Try run in android if it's giving any error thats much fixable.
it remember me to **Delete my "dart.html" import which i dont use** then this error fixed too. But before i did every solution in this page good to remember.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the rosetta when building the project if you are on a apple M1 or M2. go to the application folder, right click on the terminal, go to "get info" and check the "open using rosetta"

[image]